# Firefox stopped loading pages (including Preferences and about:config) and repeatedly prompts restart

Tags: firefox

I am running Firefox 87.0 on Ubuntu 21.04. I ran into some issues after an ubuntu update, where programs (even gnome-terminal) stopped loading all together after I boot into my system. I resolved it by forcing modprobe.blacklist=nouveau

Now my all other programs work fine. However, while my firefox opens up, it doesn't load any pages. Not even the Preferences and about:config page. If I remove all tabs, and open a new one, it would repeatly prompt me that Firefox needs to restart after update. Although restarting firefox does absolutely nothing.

I've tried creating new profiles, rebooting my system, completely removing and reinstalling firefox, nothing works.

I'm forced to install and use google chrome to ask for any suggestions, which, as you can see, works perfectly. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

I tried to run the newest firefox from official website's firefox tar ball, and the result is the same.  I've included the error messages in the terminal that I launch with.  I'm beginning to suspect it has something to do with the graphic card driver?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to "refresh" firefox?

Comment: Did you try to create a new system user and run Firefox under that user?

Comment: There will have been an update from 87 to 89, the current version. All should be fine after you log out/back in or reboot the computer. It not, then you will need to start with a new profile.

Comment: @vanadium I've just tried that, still no joy.  I've updated a screenshot, along with error messages in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337540/firefox-shows-only-blank-pages-even-aboutconfig-is-just-white

Turns out someone else also asked this question, and provided an answer as well.  It is caused by the Citrix icaclient.  Remove the current installed icaclient and reinstall it again without the app protection mode.

That's it.